# Java Class2.getClass() returns the wrong class

Tags: java

#### Class1.java

```
public class Class1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Class2() {}.getClass());
    }

}
```

#### Class2.java

```
public Class2 {
}
```

When I try to get the class for `Class2` it returns back class `Class1`. The output for the above code returns `class Class1$1`. I would expect it should return `class Class2$1`. Why is it returning a completely different class?

Comment: The anonymous class is enclosed by `Class1`, not `Class2`.

Comment: When `Class2` is moved to a separate class (and separate file), the result of `println` is the same: `class Class1$1`

Comment: Please show how "class2 is moved to a separate class and separate file" -- the class 2 you're calling in the println statement is still an inner class of class 1.

Comment: Because `new Class2() {}` is creating an **anonymous** class and that class remains enclosed by `Class1`.

Answer (score 4):

You actually have an anonymous subclass of `Class2`. This

```
System.out.println(new Class2() {}.getClass());
```

should be

```
System.out.println(new Class2().getClass());
```

And, as pointed out in the comments, the name(s) the compiler assigns to anonymous classes is an implementation detail that should not be replied upon. For example, here

```
System.out.println(new Class1() {}.getClass());
System.out.println(new Class2() {}.getClass());
System.out.println(new Class2() {}.getClass());
```

You will get different numbers in **each** case.

Comment: And that anonymous class is called `Class1$1` because it is defined inside of `Class1`. That name has nothing to with any classes or interfaces that are being extended. And it is an implementation detail that you should not rely on. If you care about the name of the class, do not use an *anonymous* class.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct behavior. The output means that your anonymous class is under Class1, which is correct - you defined your anonymous class under Class1, not Class2.

Comment: And the class name you end up with is an implementation detail that you should not rely on. If you care about the name of the class, do not use an anonymous class.